# Time zone php error log file

Tags: php, file, logging, timezone

I do not understand why the time zone on my php error log file is different than php.ini file. So for example I receive this:

[10-Dec-2014 15:50:54 UTC] PHP Notice:

where my time is 07:50 UTC

Can somebody point me on the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php Check that

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting:
    date.timezone = "YOUR TIMEZONE"
in your php.ini file?

Additionally at times it can be difficult to locate your php.ini file. You can find it by looking at

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: That's not a problem. I did it  like so: date.timezone=America/Los_Angeles. The issue is in my [code]@ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/logs/php-errors.log'); /* path to server-writable log file */[/code] which render a different time than mine

Comment: What happens when you just write date();

Comment: Something. Still 8 hours difference between.

Comment: echo "PHP time is" . date() ", System time is ".exec('date'))"; See if there's a discrepancy there.